# SSRS report for check printout

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I need to build the following check printout in SSRS, and it works fine if I have up to 12 rows, as everything fits on one page.

So the page is divided into 3 equal parts: own copy, beneficiary copy (same as own copy), and the check itself.

When I have more than 12 rows, then the check portion at the bottom gets shifted to the next page, because the first two sections push it, which is incorrect.

How can I make sure that the first part is up to 12 rows, and the second part has 12 rows on first page, with any remaining rows continue on page 2?

I tried different approaches but no luck so far.

thank you,

[image: Check layout]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` function in your SQL or `RowNumber` in SSRS. Then add a table filter to the "Own Copy" section to limit the row number to <= 12.